# Subroutine in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I am looking for a tiny example of writing in `algorithm2e` an algorithm using a subroutine.

The algorithm is called `algo`, and it recursively calls a subroutine called `proc`.
It should be something like below in one environment:

```
Algorithm 1 algo()
1 xxx
2 xxx
3 proc()
4 return
Procedure proc()
1 xxx
2 return
```

I do not want to write these two things using two different algorithm environments. 
Can anyone show me an example?

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the desired type of output would be helpful.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I do not have a working example... If I had, I would not ask the question... I need an example to write an algorithm, which has a subroutine/function inside the algorithm.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is one version.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{algorithm}[htp]
  \SetAlgoLined\DontPrintSemicolon
  \SetKwFunction{algo}{algo}\SetKwFunction{proc}{proc}
  \SetKwProg{myalg}{Algorithm}{}{}
  \myalg{\algo{}}{
  \nl xxx\;
  \nl xxx\;
  \nl \proc{}\;
  \nl \KwRet\;}{}
  \setcounter{AlgoLine}{0}
  \SetKwProg{myproc}{Procedure}{}{}
  \myproc{\proc{}}{
  \nl xxx\;
  \nl \KwRet\;}
  \caption{Algorithm with procedure}
\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

`\SetKwProg` sets up sub-environments corresponding to a proceedure or an algorithm.  `\SetKwFunction` is used to consitently typeset the names of the funictons.  Line numbers are provided by specifying `\nl` at the beginning of the relevant lines, and the relevant counter is reset before the proceedure, to give the requested numbering.

Comment: It may be better if you don't reset the line numbers in the same algorithm. That way it's clear which lines are meant when you refer to Lines 1 and 2.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Indeed, that would be my preference too.  The reset was added to show the OP's requested formatting.