# indent somelines with the usepackage algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

I want to indent all lines after this line `function(w,v` with the usepackage `algorithm2e`. How can I get that to work?

**text**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{german,t1enc}
%pseudocode.
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]

function(w,v) \\
  formed the  Suffix-Array $s$ von $w$; \\
  compare Suffix $S[i]$ with Suffix $S[j]$ and find the LCP then store the
  result in array x;

\caption{}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you wish to have a subroutine in your algorithm and that is why you wish to indent.
you should looks [at this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102602/subroutine-in-algorithm2e)

as to your code, without much work you could simply indent with `\qquad`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{german,t1enc}
%pseudocode.
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]

function(w,v) \\
  \qquad formed the  Suffix-Array $s$ von $w$; \\
  \qquad compare Suffix $S[i]$ with Suffix $S[j]$ and find the LCP then store the
  \qquad result in array x;

\caption{}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have used \Indp once after the function and it wroks.